# application interceptor com.blueware.agent.android.instrumentation.okhttp3.d@41c1cec0 returned null

Tags: android, okhttp

```
application interceptor com.blueware.agent.android.instrumentation.okhttp3.d@41c1cec0 returned null
```

When I used OkHttp3, this error occurred a NullPointerException many times! especially without a network.

Here are the details:

[image]

Here are the resource codes where the error occurred:

```
  class ApplicationInterceptorChain implements Interceptor.Chain {
private final int index;
private final Request request;
private final boolean forWebSocket;

ApplicationInterceptorChain(int index, Request request, boolean forWebSocket) {
  this.index = index;
  this.request = request;
  this.forWebSocket = forWebSocket;
}

@Override public Connection connection() {
  return null;
}

@Override public Request request() {
  return request;
}

@Override public Response proceed(Request request) throws IOException {
  // If there's another interceptor in the chain, call that.
  if (index < client.interceptors().size()) {
    Interceptor.Chain chain = new ApplicationInterceptorChain(index + 1, request, forWebSocket);
    Interceptor interceptor = client.interceptors().get(index);
    Response interceptedResponse = interceptor.intercept(chain);

    if (interceptedResponse == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("application interceptor " + interceptor
          + " returned null");
    }

    return interceptedResponse;
  }

  // No more interceptors. Do HTTP.
  return getResponse(request, forWebSocket);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It had a conflict with other SDK.